# Entity reference of a menu link gives Restricted access instead of the real data

Tags: routes, entities

I am trying to create an entity reference of a "menu link", but instead of having the menu link name I got  "- Restricted access -".
It seems to be the same problem with wysiwyg profile.
I'm using the last version of entity reference (7.x-1.1), event the dev version is the build.

I'm using admin with full right on everything.

Any idea why ?

Comment: I found out a module called "menu reference" which seems to work, but it doesn't explain why it doesn't work with entity reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an issue I found on drupal .org: https://drupal.org/node/2153463

[There is a patch inside](https://drupal.org/files/issues/entityreference-restricted_access-21534630-6.patch) to fix the issue but it doesn't seem like the final patch, so decide if you want to use it. Your alternative is to use an old version of entity reference which doesn't have this bug.